# Conditional Probability: $P(X|Y\leq y)=$ $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{y} P(X|Y=k)$?

Tags: conditional-probability

Suppose $X \sim Binomial (Y,\delta)$. 
For the random variable $X$ can I compute the following conditional probability as follows?
$P(X=x|Y\leq y)=$ $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{y} P(X=x|Y=k)$, where Y is a discrete random variable having the value of positive integers.

Comment: What is $P(X|E)$ for a *random variable* $X$ and an event $E$?

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks for the question. I revised the question.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can, provided that the summands are disjoint, i.e. that $$
\left( {X \cap Y = k} \right) \cap \left( {X \cap Y = j} \right) = \emptyset \quad \left| {\;k \ne j} \right.
$$